# Using PowerShellGet on VSTS hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, powershellget

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) hosted build agents in my build process. My builds mostly rely on the 'PowerShell' step that calls a script that I have in git. From within this script, I would like to manage PowerShell modules using PowerShellGet. For example, I would like to be able to install [pscx](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx/3.2.1.0) simply by running

```
Install-Module -Name pscx
```

Unfortunately, hosted agents use PowerShell 4 and they don't have the `PowerShellGet` module installed. As a result, the `Install-Module` function is not available.

Anybody has any suggestion to use the PowerShellGet module on VSTS hosted agent? Note that since I don't have admin rights on this machine, I can't install the msi that installs PowerShellGet for PowerShell 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use PowerShellGet, two PowerShell modules are required:

- PowerShellGet
- PackageManagement

These are available out of the box with PowerShell 5 or through the msi installer available on the PowerShell Gallery.

Instead of deploying these modules through the msi, you can simply add them to your git repository (ex: in a folder named `PsModules`). You will be able to get a hand on these modules on a machine that has either PS5 or the msi installed. They are usually in the `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folder.

Then, add the `PsModules` folders to your PSModulePath environment variable. Starting from there, it is possible to use PowerShellGet as in the following:

```
$env:PSModulePath = "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\PsModules;$env:PSModulePath"
Import-Module PowerShellGet
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -Scope currentuser
Save-Module pscx -path "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\PsModules"
import-module pscx
Write-Host '************************'
Get-Command -module pscx
```