# Azure's New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster command does not accept documented ComponentVersion option

Tags: azure, powershell

According to MS's docs for [New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.hdinsight/new-azurermhdinsightcluster),
it should accept `-ComponentVersion` as an option:

```
$httpCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($httpUserName, $clusterpassword)

$sparkConfig = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$sparkConfig.Add("spark", "2.1")

New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster `
    -ClusterName mycluster `
    -ComponentVersion $sparkConfig `
    -ClusterSizeInNodes 4 `
    -HttpCredential $httpCredential `
    -Location "Central US" `
    -OSType Linux `
    -ResourceGroupName tstcluster
```

However, this command results in:

```
##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComponentVersion'.
```

Is there a way to select the Spark version required? We used to use:

```
Add-AzureRmHDInsightComponentVersion -Config $config -ComponentName "Spark" -ComponentVersion "2.1"
```

But that's now rejected:

```
##[error]The term 'Add-AzureRmHDInsightComponentVersion' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

EDIT:

A couple of factors that were key to solving this: First, this script is run by an `Azure PowerShell Script` task in an Azure Dev Ops pipeline. Second, the PowerShell version used to run this script was 1.*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side. Make sure you have installed the [`AzureRM.HDInsight`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.HDInsight/4.1.5) powershell module, you could check it with `Get-Module AzureRM.HDInsight`.

[image]

**Sample command:**

```
$httpUserName = "joyhd"
$clusterpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force 
$httpCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($httpUserName, $clusterpassword)    
$SshCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($httpUserName, $clusterpassword)
$storageAccountName = "<storageAccountName>"
$storageAccountKey = "xxxxxxx"
$storageContainer = "testhd"

New-AzureRmHDInsightClusterConfig `
            | Add-AzureRmHDInsightComponentVersion `
                -ComponentName "Spark" `
                -ComponentVersion "2.1" `
            | New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster `
    -ClusterName joytesthd `
    -ClusterType "Spark" `
    -ClusterSizeInNodes 4 `
    -HttpCredential $httpCredential `
    -Location "eastus" `
    -OSType Linux `
    -ResourceGroupName joywebapp `
    -DefaultStorageAccountName "$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" `
    -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
    -DefaultStorageContainer $storageContainer `
    -SshCredential $SshCredential
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I've tried that. In our case, this is not something that runs locally, but runs under Azure DevOps. The script is run on a vm created and configured by Microsoft.

Comment: @DonBranson May be you could include the environment in your question.

Comment: Yes, it seems I need to. Perhaps those vms are controllable in some fashion? Or does MS just have a stock template for making them? I'll have to dig into that to find out. It seems like AzureRM.HDInsight must be installed there, just a version that doesn't recognize the ComponentVersion option for commands that are documented as supporting it.

Comment: @DonBranson Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954237/using-powershellget-on-vsts-hosted-agents), may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MS was not able to explain why a script that worked in Azure Dev Ops (then VSTS) stopped working. That is, why Add-AzureRmHDInsightComponentVersion was supported in January 2018 but not in September of that same year.

Their solution was to select the latest version of PowerShell available in a pipeline (3.*) and set the `Preferred Azure PowerShell Version` to 3.8.0.

Making those changes made the existing script workable again.